# Im working on flutter mysql authentication, i want to fetch the exact users details from my database after Login

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, authentication

I'm working on flutter mysql authentication. I want to fetch the exact users details from my database after Login but I got this problems.

Exception caught by widgets library:

> The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#80ad8):
> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

login.dart :

```
  Future login() async {
    var theUrl = "http://tluang.tech/student/login.php";
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(theUrl), body: {
      "StudentID": card.text,
      "password": pass.text,
    });
    var data = json.decode(response.body);

    if (data == "Success") {
      displayToastMessage("Login Successful!", context);
      await FlutterSession().set('card', card.text);

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Home(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      displayToastMessage("Student ID invalid!", context);
      print('ERROR');
    }
  }

homepage.dart :

child: FutureBuilder(
     future:
       FlutterSession().get('card'),
        builder: (context,
           AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
             return Text(
              snapshot.hasData
                ? snapshot.data
                : 'Loading...',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  letterSpacing: 3.0,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight:
                  FontWeight.w200));
              }),
```

[image]

Comment: Without any relevant code how can we help ? From the error log it seems like you are assigning an integer value to string variable.

Comment: How did you implement `FlutterSession().get('card')` ? What is the result of that Future ?

Comment: await FlutterSession().set('card', card.text);

Comment: I mean when you call `FlutterSession().get('card')` what are you returning from that function?

Comment: "StudentID": "123456789012",

Comment: Are you sure you are sending that in the form of String? Could you please return some random string like : "12AB" or something like that to check ?

Comment: I mean im trying to print the student ID eg. 123456789012 below library card id but it shows that red rectangle box

Comment: If you put some string value in that text widget, instead of `snapshot.data`, is it working? If it's working, then your data is not string it's an integer value as mentioned in the error log.

Comment: yes when i put string value in the text widget  it print correct.

Comment: how will i change the value.?

Comment: i need to use bigint as the value

Comment: Try with `snapshot.data.toString()`